# CSSのflex-wrapで1列目の要素のみを選択する方法は？

Tags: css

`flex-wrap`で複数の行ができた時、それぞれの行の1列目の要素を選択したいのですが、どのような方法がありますか？
できれば擬似クラス(pseudo-class)があると良いのですが、無さそうだったので。

以下のサンプルではaとcにのみスタイルを適用したいと考えてます。

```css
#outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 29px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#outer div {
  width: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div id='outer'>
<div>a</div>
<div>b</div>
<div>c</div>
<div>d</div>
</div>
```

Comment: #outer div:nth-child(1)

Comment: @yyz それだとcは選択されませんよね

Comment: 言葉足らずで申し訳ない　私は　aとc のセレクターをカンマで連結して定義してます。　#outer div:nth-child(1),#outer div:nth-child(3) {border: 1px solid #1b92ff;}

Comment: 表示列数が２列固定なら、#outer div:nth-child(2n+1)で良いみたいです。
動的に変化させるにはjavascriptで制御することになると思います。

Answer (score 1):

flex コンテナと flex アイテムのサイズが固定で、どの要素が一列目になるのかが明確な場合は、単純に [`:nth-of-type`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#nth-of-type-pseudo), [`:nth-child`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#nth-child-pseudo) 擬似クラスを用いて選択することが出来ます。

```css
#outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background: gray;
}

#outer div {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  background: lightgreen;
}

#outer div:nth-child(odd) {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: dotted red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
  <div>d</div>
</div>
```

そうでない場合、現在でも CSS では不可能です<sup>[1]</sup>。以下のスニペットに書いたように、 JavaScript を使う必要があります。

```js
const onResize = () => {
  const item = [...document.querySelectorAll("#outer > div")];
  let prev;
  const first = item.filter(e => {
    const top = e.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    if (typeof prev == "undefined" || top != prev) {
      prev = top;
      return true;
    }
    e.classList.remove("first-column");
  });
  first.map(e => e.classList.add("first-column"));
};
onResize();
window.addEventListener("resize", onResize);
```

```css
#outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background: gray;
}

#outer div {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.first-column {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: dotted red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
  <div>d</div>
  <div>e</div>
</div>
```

---

<sup>[1]: [いつか出来るようになるかもしれない](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1943)</sup>

Comment: 念のためコメントしておきますが、二つ目のコードスニペットは一列目の要素を選択する場合のコードです。二列目の要素を選択するためには、もう少しコードに手を加える必要があります。